# Liquibase <loadData> inserting string data into UUID column

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

When inserting string UUID on liquibase  tag it returning "ERROR: column  is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying". How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Change your JDBC connection URL to add the following:

```
?stringtype=unspecified
```

For example:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname?stringtype=unspecified
```